# How does one invoke a method on a ref class instance through reflection which returns a native pointer?

Tags: .net, reflection, delegates, c++-cli

I am attempting to invoke a method on a ref class instance through reflection, which returns a native pointer.

Example ref class header:

```
public ref class MyRefClass : public IDisposable
{
public:

MyNativeType* GetNativeInstance();

//Rest of the header...
}
```

here is an example of a failed attempt at reflection

```
void InvokeTheMethod(Object^ obj)
{
     MyNativeType* myNative;
     GetNativeInvoker^ del = (GetNativeInvoker^) Delegate::CreateDelegate(GetNativeInvoker::typeid, obj, "GetNativeInstance");

     //get pointer and use if bind succeeds myNative = del();
     //else handle the case where the Object does not have GetNativeInstance()
}
```

using this delegate

```
delegate MyNativeType* GetNativeInvoker();
```

When trying to create the delegate the bind fails with `ArgumentException` even if object is an instance of a ref class that has the method "GetNativeInstance" (like `MyRefClass`).  This problem has to be solved without knowing anything about obj's type at compile time other than the fact it is an `Object^`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not using Reflection.  Delegate::CreateDelegate() is only allowed on delegate types, yours isn't one.  Use Reflection to fix, Type::GetMethod() returns a method.  Like this (minus cleanup):

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Reflection;

class MyNativeType {};

public ref class MyRefClass
{
    MyNativeType* instance;
public:
    delegate void* GetNativeInvoker();

    MyRefClass() { instance = new MyNativeType; }
    MyNativeType* GetNativeInstance() { return instance; }

    static void Test() {
        MyRefClass^ obj = gcnew MyRefClass;
        MethodInfo^ mi = obj->GetType()->GetMethod("GetNativeInstance");
        Object^ result = mi->Invoke(obj, nullptr);
        void* ptr = Pointer::Unbox(result);
        System::Diagnostics::Debug::Assert(ptr == obj->GetNativeInstance());
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, using the MethodInfo works.  I guess I incorrectly assumed CreateDelegate used reflection to bind to the method.  The main thing that bothers me here is that I thought GetNativeInvoker was a delegate type.  Does the return value have something to do with this?

Comment: Erm, it made sense when I worked on the code.  Don't remember anymore.  As long as it works.